# VBA locating the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th largest cells in a column for conditional formatting

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I'm trying to find 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th largest in a column so that I can apply conditional formatting to them but it's not working correctly...

I tried: `=INDEX($V$3:$V$100, MATCH(LARGE($V$3:$V$100,1), $V$3:$V$100) , 0)` but for some reason it highlights everything, I want this one to only show/highlight the largest/biggest.

Obviously I could use Max for the biggest, but Large lets me work with other positions

Comment: Because it's apparent to both.

Comment: VBA doesn't work in `[google-spreadsheet]`. So either `[VBA]` or `[google-speradsheet]` needs to go.

Comment: @guitarthrower My bad, I meant formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `V3:V100` is the `"Applies to"` range the formula should always work for the **top left** cell of that range, in this case `V3` so try this version

`=V3=LARGE($V$3:$V$100,1)`

Excel automatically adjust for other rows: Note that you don't have $ signs for the first V3 because you want that to adjust while the range remains constant

Comment: Maybe `=$V3=LARGE($V$3:$V$100,1)` so the CF rule can affect other cells in the same row.